# forslash as the default path separator in windows?

Tags: windows, path, command-line

Since windows now accept the forslash "/" as a path separator in addition to its default backslash path separator, so that both

```
c:\windows
and c:/windows
```

are valid paths (though the former is invalid in cygwin since backslash is escape char)

Is there any chance we could set the forslash as the default path separator on windows (GUI), so that the address bar in windows will automatically use it? I heard its possible in a powershell session but anyone knows if it is also possible in a CMD session?

Thanks
M

Comment: should we move it to superuser.sxchg?

Comment: @overrider you probably right this is not a programming question. Move it please.